How can I check if a task has been added to RabbitMQ queue using Celery in Flask application?
I am working on a Flask application using Celery and RabbitMQ as the message broker.
I want to check whether the task has been successfully added to the RabbitMQ queue before it starts processing.
Currently, I am using AsyncResult(task_id) to check the status of the task. But it responds with 'Pending' when I check the task ID that has never been created.
Is there anyway to check if a task has been added to the queue in RabbitMQ using Celery in Flask?
Has anyone encountered this issue, and if so, what is the best approach to handle it?
Thank you!

You can enable task_send_sent_event in Celery.
Celery provides the task_send_sent_event setting, which emits an event when a task is successfully sent to the broker. Then use tools like Flower.
Alternatively You can use pika to inspect RabbitMQ queues directly.
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()
queue_name = 'your_queue_name'

# Check the queue status
queue_status = channel.queue_declare(queue=queue_name, passive=True)
print(f"Messages in queue: {queue_status.method.message_count}")

connection.close()

If the task was successfully added, it will be reflected in the queue's message count.
